# How to add a point to a cell when the difference of a date is < 45 days in a range of cells

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have an excel spreadsheet where there is a start date and an end date. When a person closes a ticket in less than 45 days (the difference between the start date and the end date is <45days) they are awarded 0.5 points. They also need to be sorted by month. So dates in 11 would be allocated to the points in the November column. Here is what I have so far but is not working.

```
=SUM(IF(AND(MONTH(I2:I1000)=11)DATEDIF(I2:I1000,J2:J1000,"D")<=45,0.5,0)
```

I have tried a normal IF function as well but it doesnt seem to add properly when the ranges of cells are added.

```
| Start Date | End Date   | November Points | December Points |   |
|------------|------------|-----------------|-----------------|---|
| 11/12/2019 | 11/28/2019 | 1.0             |                 |   |
| 12/1/2019  | 1/05/2019  |                 | 0.5             |   |
| 11/12/2019 | 11/30/2019 |                 |                 |   |
```

So here you can see when the start date is 11/12/2019 and the end date is 11/28/2019 0.5 points is added to the November Points cell(the total in that cell is 1.0 since there are 2 date ranges within 45 days for November). When the start date is 12/1/2019 to end date 1/05/2019 there is now 0.5 points in the December cell.

Comment: Could you add a mock-up of your data please - either screen shot or using the [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#)?  It's a bit hard to see what you mean.  There also appears to be an error in the formula you've added - should it be `=SUM(IF(AND(MONTH(I2:I1000)=11,DATEDIF(I2:I1000,J2:J1000,"D")<=45),0.5,0))`?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I have added a table and further explaination to the question. Thank you! The formula that you wrote does not function. it won't add the points in the column it just displays the 0.

Comment: Yes, didn't think my version of the formula would be correct, but the [AND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5F19B2E8-E1DF-4408-897A-CE285A19E9D9) part of your formula wouldn't work `AND(MONTH(I2:I1000)=11)DATEDIF(I2:I1000,J2:J1000,"D")<=45` - there should be a comma before the `DATEDIF` to show it's the second part of the `AND` and there should be a closing bracket at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
| - | B          | C          | D    | E               | F               | G              |
|---|------------|------------|------|-----------------|-----------------|----------------|
| 2 | Start Date | End Date   | Days | November Points | December Points | January Points |
| 3 | 12/11/2019 | 28/11/2019 | 16   |                 |                 |                |
| 4 | 01/12/2019 | 05/01/2020 | 35   |                 |                 |                |
| 5 | 12/11/2019 | 30/11/2019 | 18   |                 |                 |                |
| 6 |            |            |      | 1               | 0.5             | 0              |
```

**Formula and formatting used:**

- Cell E2:  01/11/19 (or 11/01/19 in USA) and give the cell a custom number format of `mmmm "Points"` - do this for F2 & G2.
- Column D:  `=DATEDIF(B3,C3,"d")`
- Totals in row 6:  `=COUNTIFS($D$3:$D$5,"<=45",$B$3:$B$5,">=" & E$2,$B$3:$B$5,"<" & F$2)/2`

So the `COUNTIFS` will count how many days are <=45, will check that the dates in column B are >= 1st of the month, will check that the dates in column B are < 1st of the following month.

Comment: Is there anyway I can just add a MONTH function to the Countifs to be able to tell what month it is? I guess I am confused on how it seperates the months from each other

Comment: I will mark this since it is technically correct per the question that I asked but I found that I can use the formula =SUMPRODUCT((MONTH('Jira Sheet'!$I2:$I1000)=1)*('Jira Sheet'!$N2:$N1000<>0)*('Jira Sheet'!$N2:$N1000<=45)*0.5) in this situation.